# Компиляция в рантайме

Tags: java, компиляция

Как заставить `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` сохранять байт-код не на диск, а в `Collection<Byte>` и возможно ли это вообще? Передать ему исходники в виде строки получилось, теперь осталось отучить лазать на диск для сохранения результатов...

Comment: А вы не пробовали указывать свой собственный `Writer` и `JavaFileManager`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл, сделал по этой статье (второй день эту апи в глаза вижу):
[функция eval в java своими руками](http://vampirus.ru/code/dynamic-compile-java/), не знал, что именно сделать с файлменеджером, там определённый параметр для URI используется ("byte:///"), за счёт этого и работает. Writer, насколько я понимаю, для вывода информации об ошибках используется. Всем спасибо, вопрос можно закрывать.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.